# What does the abbreviation "v.i." mean?

Tags: meaning

I see this all over books and tests. What does it mean?

Comment: Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/250449/edit) your post to provide context. On what pages does it appear? What are the words surrounding it? Can you find any examples online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means **verb intransitive** . Though I could help you more if you provide a short example.

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviations a dictionary uses are explained in the first pages of a dictionary. It is worthwhile reading these introductoty pages.

Comment: You can say that again!